# Exclude @CLASS Property from JSON while using MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, json, jackson, restful-architecture

Restfule Service is returning json output something like

```
"@CLASS": "myPackage.myProject.Car"
"date": "2015-09-30 00:00:00.0"
"carId": 123
"carName": "ABCD"
```

When I am trying to create Car object from this json output using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, it throws error saying unrecognizable property @CLASS. Can you use ObjectMapper to avoid this property and create Car object? I can not make changes to Restful service.

Comment: can you show your annotated `Car` class? didn't understood your question properly but have you tried `@JsonIgnore` on the property which you want to exclude.

Comment: The property `@CLASS` is not actually  a property inside car object. `@CLASS` property shows the complete package path of Car Class.

Comment: you could include the definition of your POJO class?

Comment: you can try this `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`

Comment: or this     **new ObjectMapper().configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);**